# Is it possible to use gpu directly from virtual machine on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtual-machine, gpu

I'm Ubuntu user and i'd like to install windows and get directly access to gpu (NVidia 1060 6 Gb) to unity 3D and gaming, i've read a lot of information about this possibility on internet but i didn't find something usefull.

I've tried to use virtualbox - in virtualbox it's impossible to to something like that, i've installed vmware pro during creation vm i shared 3GB of GPU, but it still virtual and i have some freezes and problems with it.

May be i should use another software for virtualization or i just haven't full image of it. I'll be very thankfull for information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in VirtualBox with the Guest Additions installed.  It requires a processor with virtualization instructions and the instructions enabled in BIOS.

In the VirtualBox manager, adjust the settings of your VM by going to  <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Display</kbd> → <kbd>Screen</kbd> and ticking the following checkboxes:

- ☑ Enable 3D Acceleration
- ☑ Enable 2D Acceleration

For details and limitations, see these sections of the VirtualBox manual:

- [4.5.1. Hardware 3D Acceleration (OpenGL and Direct3D 8/9)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d)
- [4.5.2. Hardware 2D Video Acceleration for Windows Guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-2d)

If you still have trouble, you might want to consult nVidia's [Virtual GPU Software User Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/latest/grid-vgpu-user-guide/).

Comment: I have a big troubles with virtualbox, i swithed to Manjaro and i still have it :( https://imgs.info/i/cLxfN